# phpmyadminをサブディレクトリで運用できない

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

やりたいことは
http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin　にアクセスすると
/usr/share/phpMyAdmin にアクセスしてPHPを実行出来る様にする事です。

環境
NGINX1.8
PHP5.4

**/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf**

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
  rewrite_log on;
  error_log /opt/nginx/logs/phpmyadmin_error.log notice;
  root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
  rewrite ^/phpmyadmin/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index   index.php;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin$fastcgi_script_name;
      include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**/opt/nginx/logs/phpmyadmin_error.log**

```
2015/05/11 11:20:30 [error] 51293#0: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

もう３日悩んでいます。回答でなくてもヒントでもいいのでお願いします。

アドバイスいただいた件も含めて修正しました。

```
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
  alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$1;
}

location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
  alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$1;
  index index.php
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  include         fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

これでエラーはでなくなりましたがphpが実行されずにダウンロードされます。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687774/ubuntu-14-nginx-php5-fpm-installed-phpmyadmin-but-403-forbidden-access これを観る限りですが、 `index index.php` が抜けているか、`disable_symlinks off` が抜けているなど無いでしょうか？

Comment: "access forbidden" ですので、nginx 側で禁止されていると思うのですが、それらしい設定は見当たりませんね。
ファイルパーミッションや SELinux だと違うエラーメッセージになると思いますし。
 
切り分けとして、/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/test.txt を作成し、URL:/phpmyadmin/test.txt へアクセスした場合はどうなりますでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
mattn 様　リンクのstackoverflowはsymlink が貼ってある場合ですので今回の件とは違うと思います。一応、ご指摘頂いたのは試してみましたがダメでした。でも、とても参考になりましたのでありがとうございます。
TaichiYanagiya 様　こちらのミスでした。コンソールからcurlでアクセスしていたのですが自アドレスがdenyになってました。

Comment: 自己解決したのであればその内容は質問に追記するのではなく自分で回答としてポストして承認してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### 自己解決です。

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
  alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
  index index.php index.html;
  location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$1;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include       fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

ポイントはlocationディレクティブの優先順位を確認する事！
locationにrootを使用しない事！
むやみにrewriteを使用しない事！

途中であきらめかけてこんなコードも書いたりしました。

```
location /phpmyadmin {
  rewrite ^/phpmyadmin(/|)$ /phpMyAdmin/index.php redirect;
}
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.*)$ {
  rewrite ^/phpmyadmin/(.*)$ /phpMyAdmin/$1 redirect;
}
location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.php)$ {
  root /usr/share;
  index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include       fastcgi_params;
}
location ~* ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
  root /usr/share;
}
```

これでも機能しますがphpMyAdminにリライトしており本来の趣旨とは外れるので却下です。
誰かの参考になればと思い記録しておきます。