# NginxでphpMyAdminにアクセスしようとするとFile not foundと返される

Tags: centos, nginx, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdminのインストールは以下のようにしました。

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
$ sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

データベースは作成済みです。

---

**環境**

CentOS 7.1.1503
Nginx 1.8.0
php 5.4.16
MariaDB 10.1.7

### phpMyAdminにアクセスできない

独自ドメインは仮に`example.me`とします。

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`に以下を追記しました。

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name  phpmyadmin.example.me;

       location /phpMyAdmin {
                root /usr/share;
                index index.php;
                }

        location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin.+\.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

一応以下のコマンドも入力しました。

```
$ sudo chown nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

この状態でMySQLとNginxを再起動し、`http://phpmyadmin.example.me/phpMyAdmin`にアクセスしてみましたが、「File not found.」と返ってきます。

---

内容の変更を試してみました。

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`の内容を以下に変更します。

（http://oxynotes.com/?p=8457の内容をほぼ丸コピさせて頂きました。ただ、nginx.confではなく、conf.d/phpmyadmin.confに書きました。）

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name phpmyadmin.example.me;

        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        root html;

        location /phpMyAdmin {
            alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin(.+\.php)$ {
                alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                allow 160.16.74.43;
                deny  all;
            }
        }

    }
```

この状態でNginxを再起動し`http://phpmyadmin.example.me/phpMyAdmin`にアクセスしたところ、画像のようなメッセージが返ってきました。

https://kie.nu/2KLH

もとからファイル名も表示されていません。（加工したのはモザイク部分だけです）

---

なかなか情報が見つからず、苦戦している状況です。

初心者ですみませんが、お力を貸していただけると嬉しいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちら [nginx - phpmyadminをサブディレクトリで運用できない](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10018/) が参考になりそうです。

Comment: >argusさん　コメントありがとうございます。リンク先のページを参考に設定しましたが、ファイルがダウンロードされてしまいます..

Comment: 参考にならずすみません。回答が付いていますので、しばらくしたらコメントを削除します。

Comment: いえいえ、僕にとっては上手くいきませんでしたが、他の人にとっては参考になる可能性もありますよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2つ目の設定についてコメントします。

- 「location ~ ^/phpmyadmin(.+.php)$」だと URL のパスが「/phpMyAdmin/」(大文字含む)にマッチしないので、FastCGI ではなく普通のファイルとみなされてしまいます。
- 「fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME」には PHPファイル名を "$1" で渡す必要があります。

したがって、location 箇所を以下のようにすればいいと思います。

```
location /phpMyAdmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.php)$ {                            #変更
        alias /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;                                #必要なし？ 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$1;     #変更
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        allow 160.16.74.43;
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Comment: >Taichi Yanagiyaさん　ご解答ありがとうございます。その設定でphpMyAdminにアクセスしたところ、上手くいきました！とても助かりました。